# Gradle: add .jar to /war/WEB-INF/lib

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gradle

I'm having difficulty getting Gradle to add a dependency to my /war/WEB-INF/lib directory in a Google Web Application Project.

```
apply plugin: 'java' 
apply plugin: 'war' 

repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
}

dependencies { 
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4' 
}
```

Using Eclipse, gson-2.2.4.jar shows up in Project and External Dependencies (project compiles) but doesn't get added to /war/WEB-INF/lib (NoClassDef exception at runtime since it can't find the .jar)

I've tried changing webAppDir, webAppDirName, and editing the war task all to no avail.